# Extracting *.tif agricultural area from shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I am attempting to extract from an image using Esri shapefile that is in the zip file **RR_KZKD2012**

In ArcGis the spatial reference is Projected Coordinate System: WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_43N.

Then am using arcgis extract by mask to clip my **Mg1.tif** using  **RR_KZKD2012**

The output tif file is not extracted properly. I do not understand why see example:
[image]

am using different scenarios but not work..

I am sharing the link below...please have a look and see if you can see where it is going wrong.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By0CgkNTboOXMDZmal9xMFV2Rjg/view

I have many more to do.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For some tips on how to structure your question to attract potential answerers I recommend that you review http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353.  Would you be able to re-read your question and then use the **edit** button to revise it to a state that is much clearer and contains a single question mark, please?

Comment: Dammit! I nearly had an answer done... The shapefile needs to be repaired with Repair Geometry http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003v000000 and defined to WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_43N then it works just fine with Extract by Mask http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002n000000.htm If you could reopen the question @PolyGeo I can submit the answer.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I'll re-open, but can you edit the question to make what it is asking clear too?

Comment: @PolyGeo, will do. I understand the question based on the data.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson It's a shame that following a link to download the data was needed to understand the question.  I suspect some/many potential answerers pass on questions that include links to data - I know that I do.

Comment: I generally do @PolyGeo both for fear of virus/malware and I.T. policy. I can't get to DropBox but I can get to Google Drive. I can understand the reluctance to visit a site or download data. Anand, it is better to include a picture than a link unless someone specifically asks for it in a comment. Almost nobody will download data but everyone will see a picture.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things that must be done. Using your data I [set the spatial reference of the shape](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000077000000) file to WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_43N (it was undefined) and then repaired the geometry with [Repair Geometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003v000000).

After that the image extracted properly with [Extract by Mask](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002n000000.htm):
[image]

This could be scripted if you have python ability but can also be done on batch.

Comment: Hai Michael Miles-Stimson....Thanks for your Answer.I follow  your scenario and i got correct clipped image.